# How to reduce vmware workstation image size

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I Installed sql server and some other softwares in windows on Vmware workstation.   It all took around 25 gb size.

I need to use this configuration on another machine.

My question is: Is it possible to reduce the virtual image size?

Comment: Fixed some grammar and some formatting. For readability.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation from VMWare clearly outlines the steps required to shrink a virtual machine](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_disk_shrink.html).

1. Launch the control panel.

   - Windows guest — double-click the VMware Tools icon in the system tray, or choose Start > Settings > Control Panel, then double-click VMware Tools.
   - Linux or FreeBSD guest — become root (su -), then run vmware-toolbox.
2. Click the Shrink tab.
3. Select the virtual disks you want to shrink, then click Prepare to Shrink. 
   A dialog box tracks the progress of the wiping process. Note: If you deselect some partitions, the whole disk is still shrunk. However, those partitions are not wiped for shrinking, and the shrink process does not reduce the size of the virtual disk as much as it could with all partitions selected.
4. Click Yes when VMware Tools finishes wiping the selected disk partitions. 
   A dialog box tracks the progress of the shrinking process. Shrinking disks may take considerable time.
5. Click OK to finish.